# Prove that ${\rm Ker}f=\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$, and $f:G\to \text{Sym}(G/H)$ is the left-coset action.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am trying to prove that ${\rm Ker}f=\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$, and $f:G\to \text{Sym}(G/H)$ is the left-coset action.

Here is what I have

$$\begin{align}
k\in K=\text{Ker} f &\iff k\cdot xH=xH, \forall xH\in G/H\\
&\iff k\in G_{xH}, \forall xH\\
&\iff k\in \bigcap_{xH\in G/H} G_{xH}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}$$

Now we want to show that $G_{xH}=xHx^{-1}=\{ xhx^{-1} \mid x\in G\}$.

$$\begin{align}
g\in G_{xH} &\iff g\cdot xH=xH\\
&\iff gxh_1=xh_2, \ \ \ h_1,h_2\in H\\
&\iff g=xh_2 h_1^{-1} x^{-1}\\
&\iff g \in xHx^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Hence $G_{xH}=xHx^{-1}=\{ xhx^{-1} \mid x\in G\}$.

Back to $(*)$,

$$\begin{align}
k\in \bigcap_{xH\in G/H} G_{xH} &\iff k\in \bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}, 
\end{align}$$

which is true iff

$$K=\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}.$$

Is it correct? I appreciate any comments. Thanks.

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for your comment and for the edit, it looks so much better now!

Comment: In the second chain of equivalences, the last equivalence is unclear. If $g\in xHx^{-1}$, then there exists $h$ such that $g=xhx^{-1}$. It is not evident that you can write it in the form you give. Better to use that $xH=yH$ if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$. So $gxH=xH$ if and only if $x^{-1}gx\in H$, if and only if $g\in xH x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}(xH) &=\{g\in G\mid gxH=xH\} \\
 &=\{g\in G\mid x^{-1}gxH=H\} \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
Now, call $g':=x^{-1}gx$, whence $g=xg'x^{-1}$. From $(1)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}(xH) &=\{xg'x^{-1}\in G\mid g'H=H\} \\
&=x\{g'\in G\mid g'H=H\}x^{-1} \\
&=x\{g'\in G\mid g'\in H\}x^{-1} \\
&=xHx^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}
Therefore:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker}f &=\bigcap_{xH\in G/H}\operatorname{Stab}(xH) \\
&=\bigcap_{x\in G}\operatorname{Stab}(xH) \\
&=\bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}